# Not sure where to go from this point in Python?

Tags: python

Here's my problem: [image]

I have everything covered up until the third part of the question. I just don't know where to go from there. Can I get some help on what to do?

Here's what I have so far:

```
userInt = int(input('Enter integer (0 - 155):\n'))

userFloat = float(input('Enter float:\n'))

userCharacter = input('Enter character:\n')

userString = input('Enter string:\n')

print(userInt, userFloat, userCharacter, userString)

print(userString, userCharacter, userFloat, userInt)
```

Comment: use the `chr` function maybe?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: The instruction seems quite specific, you need to use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [chr() function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_chr.asp) documentation, it's quite clear.

Plus, I think you should also look at those:

- [join() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)
- [reverse() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_reverse.htm)

> **Update**
>   It seems your problem is with formatting the the output, so here it is:
>
> [python-string-formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36)

Comment: I'm aware of the chr() function, I'm just not sure what to put in order to make it print "99 converted to a character is c" as the assignment requires. (I am brand new to coding, so excuse my ignorance)

Comment: There is no problem with not knowing, but I will not make a better answer than what you can find on the pages I linked. But if your problem is with formatting text, you should have been more specific about that (I updated my answer). I also think the questions 1 and 2 want you to use the `join` and `reverse` functions.